# Reading external styles.xml file and apply to our workbook

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm gathering that if we can read external `styles.xml` file and apply to our workbook using `OpenXML` would be more efficiently than styling in our code. I have done a lot of research but still not get any solution.

Please tell me if it possible or not and give me some resources (if any) about this.

Comment: The Excel file should be self-contained so I don't believe you can have an external stylesheet. What you could do is maybe rewrite the styles.xml in the XSLX file with the one you have externally but I've never done this myself. Doesn't an Excel template file meet your requirement?

Comment: Oh, as you said, it means I can define a template for this?, perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's *possible* to modify `styles.xml` directly but that doesn't mean it's a good idea.  I've seen a few people try to work directly with the styles but *I have yet to see it turn out well* -- and these are people with many years of experience with XML, coding and Excel is general, who figured they had exhausted usability of Excel's built-in features and figured they could do a better job at it than Microsoft can.

If you are confident that you can build a stylesheet more appropriate for your project (than what Excel's developer provided) you'll be able to find full specifications by researching **ISO 29500-1**.

- [Overview from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML#ISO/IEC_29500:2008)
- [ISO/IEC 29500-1:2016](https://www.iso.org/standard/71691.html) (7000+ pages)
- [Generating Excel 2010 Workbooks by using the Open XML SDK 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh180830(v=office.14).aspx)
- [How to: Manipulate Office Open XML Formats Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa982683(v=office.12).aspx)
- [How to Diagnose Excel file corruption and Repair Workbooks](http://www.spreadsheet1.com/how-to-diagnose-excel-file-corruption-and-repair-workbooks.html)
- [[Solved] File corrupt and therefore cannot be repaired](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=57099)

*I'll admit I'm very curious about how Excel's stylesheet is no longer suitable for your organization's requirements!